# Undefined property: stdClass: PHP API

Tags: php, api, class, stock

I am using bees found online to be able to easily obtain stock prices:

https://keithweaverca.medium.com/using-a-stock-market-api-4ce65b7c67ac

I call it many times having to complete a list, I have inserted it inside a function. Sometimes random results give the error:

*Undefined property: stdClass:*

````
    if($ticker != ''){
        $API_KEY = "F54SPPZ6VDOEO5TX";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=".$ticker."&apikey=" . $API_KEY));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $result = json_decode($server_output);
        
        $date = new DateTime(date ("Y/m/d"));
        $date ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        
        
        $dataForAllDays = $result->{'Time Series (Daily)'};
        $dataForSingleDate = $dataForAllDays->{$date ->format('Y-m-d')};
        echo $dataForSingleDate->{'1. open'} . '<br/>';
        
        
    } else{
        echo "Errore API ";
    }
}  ``` 

The error is on the $ dataForAllDays, the lines are for getting yesterday's day (they work)
````

Comment: Do not add API keys in question.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing with that code, this happens when the `$ticker` variable you are using isn't valid.

For example, attempting to make the request with a ticker of `XXX` gives me the following value in `$result`:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["Error Message"]=>
  string(125) "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_DAILY."
}
```

In this case, I then get the full warning message:

```
Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$Time Series (Daily)
```

which makes sense, as the response from the API does not have a `Time Series (Daily)` field.

The fix for this would be to validate that the response you are receiving from the API is formatted in a way that you can handle (eg, checking `isset($result->{'Time Series (Daily)'})`) before proceeding.